# Regex to find a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

Regex to find a string in C# which starts with a space and ends with a space and have one or more commas in between.

example
MELVILLE 203 31-MAR-11 15 DENNY WAY, ALFRED COVE, 6154 WA $19,040 34 POOL

Here I want to get the  DENNY WAY, ALFRED COVE, 6154 WA as output

Comment: Thats an incredibly vague question. Either ask it properly or do some research into regex as it seems like there is a simple solution. How about an example of strings that would or wouldn't match?

Comment: According to your recently added example, your specifications are way off. How are the spaces before DENNY and after WA different from any other space in that text sample? Your rules are not precise enough. Think about them again and edit your post.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on in this question. As Tim said, the example is very different from the "specification", and neither of them makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@" .*?,.*? "
```

You didn't mention whether spaces are also allowed *inside* the string. If they aren't, use

```
@" [^ ]*,[^ ]* "
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only match a single comma in between?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, the dot matches any character, including the comma. So will the negated character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 @" \S+?,\S+? "
```

Sure...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
\s[^\s,]+(,[^\s,]+?)+\s
```